# How to cast a Date for this date format

Tags: java, date

How do I cast this format `Nov 18 2013 6:56PM` in a Date object in Java?

This is the format of date that I receive from a DB to which my app connects.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't cast a `String` to a `Date`; you convert it with a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a `DateFormatter` instance for this purpose. The format string for your sample is
`MMM dd yyyy K:mma`

See the reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).